# Loop through columns in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my Access database, I have a query (call it `qrySource`) that adds a new column every month. When you run the query in March, the datasheet looks like this:

```
ID   January   February   March
1      20%        50%      100%
2      10%        60%      95%%
3      25%        60%      80%
4      20%        30%      75%
5      15%        50%      100%
```

Next month it would have an April column, etc.

I have another query that pulls from this one:

```
SELECT qrySource.ID, qrySource.January AS Jan, qrySource.February AS Feb, qrySource.March AS Mar
FROM qrySource
```

As it stands, I have to update this query every month to pull in the new monthly column from qrySource.

(I can't just use `SELECT *`, because the real query is more complex than this. For one thing, it pulls fields from several "source" queries.)

Is there a way to make this query "loop" through all the columns in qrySource without knowing exactly how many there are?

Comment: yes - but you should redesign this.  do not add new columns every month, instead add new ROWS every month into a stable table.  with columns like id, month, value

Comment: This is poor database table design.  Instead of adding new columns as the date progresses, you should be adding new `records`.  Just keep a single date/timestamp column, and if you want to _view_ your table with months as columns, then build a report which does that.

Comment: to answer your question, yes you can loop through fieldnames but you nee `VBA` for it.  not possible in plain SQL

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The database actually has a query (not a table) like you describe, and I am concurrently trying to figure out how to convert that into the result I want. A crosstab query, I think, but that's a whole other question (and probably a newbie one, at that.)

Comment: Yes...crosstab sounds correct to me